# Declarar uma array bidimensional em javascript sem numero de posições especifica

Tags: javascript, array, array-multidimensional

Como cria uma array bidimensional no javascript onde não precisa colocar um tamanho em especifico, e ele vai crescendo no decorrer que eu adiciono coisas.

Answer (score 1):

Não existe arrays multidimensionais em javascript, existe arrays aninhados (jagged array), que são arrays dentro de arrays.

Não é preciso indicar o tamanho do array, mesmo que indique um tamanho com: `var arr = new Array(2);`
poderá adiconar novos elemento ao array.

Pode criar arrays aninhados desta forma:

```js
var jaggedArray = [];

var array1d_1 = ["maria", "joana"];

var array1d_2 = ["rita", "lena", "leonor"];

jaggedArray.push(array1d_1, array1d_2);

console.log(jaggedArray);
```

pode ate setar um array1d logo ao respectivo index:

```
jaggedArray[0] = array1d_1;
jaggedArray[1] = array1d_2;

// para ter acesso
console.log(jaggedArray[1][2]); // leonor
```